# Can we store regex as an environment variable in vault?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The regex I need is `/^(?!(?:.*?\b\d{7,}\b){4}).+/` and I am storing it as `^(?!(?:.*?\b\d{7,}\b){4}).+` so that I can do a new RegExp(envVariable) and use it. But it comes to my code's environment variable as `/^(?!(?:.*?\\b\\d7\\b)4).*?\\b\\d4\\b/` when I bring it to the codebase while building the project. How can I store in in vault so it can be extracted fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encode/decode technique.

Mechanism:

1. Encode your regex string with base64

```js
console.log(btoa("^(?!(?:.*?\\b\\d{7,}\\b){4}).+"))
```

2. Save this string to vault
3. Decode string and create regexp from it.

```js
console.log(new RegExp(atob('Xig/ISg/Oi4qP1xiXGR7Nyx9XGIpezR9KS4r')))
```